# IPC::Run split parameters

Tags: perl, cmd, special-characters, ipc, command-line-arguments

I use IPC::Run and I want run command (for example):

```
my @cmd = ("C:/test.cmd", "key=value");
IPC::Run::run \@cmd, '>', "C:\\log" or die "Failed running\n";
```

But realy run next command: `C:/test.cmd key value`

Why IPC::Run split parameter with "=" (key=value) for two parameters key and value?

Comment: Seems to work fine for me (using your same example), what does `test.cmd` do ?

Comment: Please post the rest of your demonstration

Comment: I run next command @cmd = ("C:/hdp/pig/bin/pig.cmd", "-p", "fname=testfile", "C:/test.pig"); , but pig run with next parameters:
-p
fname
testfile
C:/test.pig

Comment: Again, please provide something runnable that demonstrate this.

Answer (score 1):

From `help cmd`:

> The special characters that require quotes are:
>
> ```
> <space>
> &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~
> ```

Use quotes:

```
my @cmd = ("C:/test.cmd", "\"key=value\"");
```